# c# petapoco object to datagridview, change column order

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a bussiness object like this:

```
[PetaPoco.TableName("cars")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("id")]
public class Cars : CarObject
{
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [DisplayName("Column Name")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string Engine { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string BHP { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string Year { get; set; }

}
```

And I display in DataGridView like this:

```
List<Cars> ret = db.Query<Cars>("select * from cars").ToList();
if(ret != null)
    dgv.DataSource = ret; // .OrderBy(o => o.Year).ToList();
```

However, seems that DGV put columns like in object (design time) order. I could alter this by using a loop with DGV DisplayIndex property but there is a simple solution, some attribute decorate?

Thanks in advance,

PS. I tried also using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but seems that for WinForms isn't working. The DGV isn't able to bind that attributes.

```
[Display(Name = "Custom Name", Order = 2)]
```

Any hack? Thanks very much.

Comment: You can create columns in designer with your order and set `AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Tim Van Wassenhove**'s elegant solution, I managed to do exactly what I wanted.

http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/04/control-the-order-of-properties-in-your-class/

It requires a modified BindingList<> class (I modified a bit more)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PropertyOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    private int order;

    public PropertyOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return this.order; }
    }
}

class PropertyOrderBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, ITypedList
{
    public PropertyOrderBindingList(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
        //
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection typePropertiesCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        return typePropertiesCollection.Sort(new PropertyDescriptorComparer());
    }

    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return string.Format("A list with Properties for {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

class PropertyDescriptorComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;
        if (x == null) return 1;
        if (y == null) return -1;

        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptorX = x as PropertyDescriptor;
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptorY = y as PropertyDescriptor;

        PropertyOrderAttribute propertyOrderAttributeX = propertyDescriptorX.Attributes[typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute)] as PropertyOrderAttribute;
        PropertyOrderAttribute propertyOrderAttributeY = propertyDescriptorY.Attributes[typeof(PropertyOrderAttribute)] as PropertyOrderAttribute;

        if (propertyOrderAttributeX == propertyOrderAttributeY) return 0;
        if (propertyOrderAttributeX == null) return 1;
        if (propertyOrderAttributeY == null) return -1;

        return propertyOrderAttributeX.Order.CompareTo(propertyOrderAttributeY.Order);
    }
}
```

Now, just decorate the poco object attributes with order:

```
[DefaultValue(null)]
[DisplayName("Column Name")]
[PropertyOrder(3)]
public string Color { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(null)]
[PropertyOrder(1)]
public string Engine { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(null)]
[PropertyOrder(0)]
public string BHP { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(null)]
[PropertyOrder(2)]
public string Year { get; set; }
```

And query like this

```
List<Cars> ret2 = db.Query<Cars>("select * from cars").ToList();

PropertyOrderBindingList<Cars> ret = new PropertyOrderBindingList<Cars>(ret2);
```

The properties will be in custom order.